# "AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the <GUID> directory

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

The situation of getting list of tenants of user. When user is logged in directory where he is a member, the exception doesn't occur. Otherwise it does, but this user is assigned to that directory as Guest.

```
Exception: {
    "error":"invalid_grant",
    "error_description":"AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the GUID directory.\r\nTrace ID: GUID\r\nCorrelation ID: GUID\r\nTimestamp: 2017-08-03 14:32:32Z",
    "error_codes":[50034],
    "timestamp":"2017-08-03 14:32:32Z",
    "trace_id":"GUID",
    "correlation_id":"GUID"
}
```

Stack shows on AcquireTokenSilentAsync.

Comment: Please include some information about what software/language/platform you are using and the code that produces the error

Comment: If you dont sanitise the guids, Microsoft engineers that have access to logs can help you.

Comment: This question is related to the blogpost about B2B users in multi-tenant applications: https://hajekj.net/2017/07/24/creating-a-multi-tenant-application-which-supports-b2b-users/

Answer (score 0):

If you were not developing an multi-tenant app, to get the token from Azure AD the user sign-in should be in that tenant.

And if you were developing an multi-tenant app, we should replace tenant with `common` in the authorization/token request(refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview)).

### Update

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer @Fei Xue. Yes this multi-tenant app and we use common. Actually we implemented this approach [link](https://hajekj.net/2017/07/24/creating-a-multi-tenant-application-which-supports-b2b-users/#comment-6) to change active directory. And now we have a problem of getting list tenants for user who is a guest in that active directory.

Comment: I am also testing the code sample you mentioned and it works well for me. Can you check the user account you tested is the guest of tenant by login Azure AD portal->Azure Active Directory-All users-Find that user? I also update a figure for the test result. Please feel to let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to work with MS Account just fine, can you try with B2B Azure AD account? Azure AD issues the token (it looks just fine) but when requesting token for another resource, it fails. It all seems perfectly fine to me, I would suspect either ADAL or AAD to have some sort of bug. I will try to go through the requests with WireShark or something when I have time to see what is going on the background.

Comment: Update: So I tracked the communication with Fiddler and managed to trace all the requests coming out from ADAL: it appears that the error mentioned above happens when using the refresh token obtained during the sign-in into the second directory to obtain token for another resource. I verified the refresh token used - it doesn't seem to be a malfunction in the TokenCache or ADAL itself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was really curious with what was wrong - and it was actually a mistake I made in the sample (I didn't even notice from the Fiddler logs, what a shame). The issue was that I have been using the `common` endpoint everywhere for the token cache and obtaining new tokens. This seems to work for Microsoft Account but not for B2B users. I have updated the [code sample](https://github.com/hajekj/aad-b2b-multitenant) to include the fixes for the authority URL to always take in the tenant's id instead of the common namespace - which really shouldn't be used anyways. More on that on [Vittorio's blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/26/the-common-endpoint-walks-like-a-tenant-talks-like-a-tenant-but-is-not-a-tenant/).

Answer (score -1):

try to use User Principal Name instead of email